# Ignore proxy for specific request

Tags: ember.js

**How do I prevent Ember from proxying specific requests?**

I have an API listening on port 3000, so when I serve my Ember app I run:

```
ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

Everything runs fine except when my app sends Bootstrap GET requests to my API (which isn't meant to handle them). Here's the error I get:

```
GET /assets/bootstrap.css.map - - ms - -
Error proxying to http://localhost:3000
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

The page ends up loading correctly, but it takes a long time because it's waiting for my API to timeout the request.

Comment: That sounds like a bug, how are you including bootstrap?

Comment: Either include that file or let your server respond with a 404. However in no way you should use `ember serve` for production!

Comment: I'm including Bootstrap in ember-cli-build.js: 

app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
  destDir: 'fonts'
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue went away when I removed `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */` from `bootstrap.css`.